# Need alternative to filters/observers for Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, performance, observer-pattern

Rails has a nice set of filters (before_validation, before_create, after_save, etc) as well as support for observers, but I'm faced with a situation in which relying on a filter or observer is far too computationally expensive.  I need an alternative.

The problem: I'm logging web server hits to a large number of pages.  What I need is a trigger that will perform an action (say, send an email) when a given page has been viewed more than X times.  Due to the huge number of pages and hits, using a filter or observer will result in a lot of wasted time because, 99% of the time, the condition it tests will be false.  The email does *not* have to be sent out right away (i.e. a 5-10 minute delay is acceptable).

What I am instead considering is implementing some kind of process that sweeps the database every 5 minutes or so and checks to see which pages have been hit more than X times, recording that state in a new DB table, then sending out a corresponding email.  It's not exactly elegant, but it will work.

Does anyone else have a better idea?

Comment: I don't want to post this as an answer because I have not researched it thoroughly but does a google search for 'rails cron' come within your problem domain? If so, I bet your question could be a lot more specific.

Comment: I know! test the condition only when it's true, that way you save 99% of processing time. :D

Answer (score 1):

Rake tasks are nice! But you will end up writing more custom code for each background job you add. Check out the Delayed Job plugin http://blog.leetsoft.com/2008/2/17/delayed-job-dj

DJ is an asynchronous priority queue that relies on one simple database table. According to the DJ website you can create a job using *Delayed::Job.enqueue()* method shown below.

```
class NewsletterJob < Struct.new(:text, :emails)
  def perform
    emails.each { |e| NewsletterMailer.deliver_text_to_email(text, e) }
  end    
end  

Delayed::Job.enqueue( NewsletterJob.new("blah blah", Customers.find(:all).collect(&:email)) )
```

Comment: +1, there's no reason to write a background job daemon when there are billions of them already implemented. Background Job, Beanstalkd, Delayed Job....

Answer (score 1):

I was once part of a team that wrote a custom ad server, which has the same requirements:  monitor the number of hits per document, and do something once they reach a certain threshold.  This server was going to be powering an existing very large site with a lot of traffic, and scalability was a real concern.  My company hired two Doubleclick consultants to pick their brains.

Their opinion was:  The fastest way to persist any information is to write it in a custom Apache log directive.  So we built a site where every time someone would hit a document (ad, page, all the same), the server that handled the request would write a SQL statement to the log:  "INSERT INTO impressions (timestamp, page, ip, etc) VALUES (x, 'path/to/doc', y, etc);" -- all output dynamically with data from the webserver.  Every 5 minutes, we would gather these files from the web servers, and then dump them all in the master database one at a time.  Then, at our leisure, we could parse that data to do anything we well pleased with it.

Depending on your exact requirements and deployment setup, you could do something similar.  The computational requirement to check if you're past a certain threshold is still probably even smaller (guessing here) than executing the SQL to increment a value or insert a row.  You could get rid of both bits of overhead by logging hits (special format or not), and then periodically gather them, parse them, input them to the database, and do whatever you want with them.

Answer (score 0):

When saving your Hit model, update a redundant column in your Page model that stores a running total of hits, this costs you 2 extra queries, so maybe each hit takes twice as long to process, but you can decide if you need to send the email with a simple if.

Your original solution isn't bad either.

Answer (score 0):

I have to write something here so that stackoverflow code-highlights the first line.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :increment_fancy_counter

  private

  def increment_fancy_counter
    # somehow increment the counter here
  end
end

# lib/tasks/fancy_counter.rake
namespace :fancy_counter do
  task :process do
    # somehow process the counter here
  end
end
```

Have a cron job run `rake fancy_counter:process` however often you want it to run.

Comment: I hadn't considered making it into a rake:task.  Thanks!